# Scraping with Scrapy and Django Integration

Tags: scrapy

i am new in django . i am following [this](https://ruddra.com/posts/django-1-7-scrapy/) link . but when i run scrapy crawl example command in terminal it give error . i not unstand what problem in my code .

```
import  scrapy
from example_bot.example_bot.items import ExampleDotcdComItem

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/'
    ]
    def parse(self,response):

       title = response.css(".truncate a::text").extract()
       description = response.css("#featured-carousel .generic-green").css("::text").extract()
       #car_location = response.css(".generic-gray::text").extract()
       #car_img = response.css(".pic::attr(data-original)").extract()
       #return CarrecordItem(car_name=car_name,car_price=car_price,location= car_location)
       return ExampleDotcdComItem(title=title, description=description)
```

setting.py

```
import os
import sys

DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = 'C:/Users/Muhammad Shahzad/PycharmProjects/example_project/example_project'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'example_project.settings'

sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
BOT_NAME = 'example_bot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['example_bot.spiders']
```

item.py

```
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from example_project.app.models import ExampleDotCom

class ExampleDotcdComItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = ExampleDotCom

import scrapy


class ExampleBotItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ExampleDotCom(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

when i run command scrapy crawl example it give error plz help me how to run and solve this  problem 
  ****File "C:\Users\Muhammad Shahzad\PycharmProjects\example_project\example_bot\example_bot\spiders\example.py", line 2, in 
    from example_bot.example_bot.items import ExampleDotcdComItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example_bot.example_bot'
(venv) C:\Users\Muhammad Shahzad\PycharmProjects\example_project\example_bot**>**

Answer (score 0):

In your **scraper**, you are importing your item i.e. `from example_bot.example_bot.items import ExampleDotcdComItem` and, it looks like there is an issue with the path of item which you are trying to load. Update your path and hopefully, it will work

Comment: when i add path without directory then show error , can you tell me how import it

Comment: Can you please share project directory view? Let me see how you have placed scrapy files

Comment: project directory is below plz check it

Answer (score 0):

First bug i see is  The file name is **item.py**
but you are importing **ExampleDotcdComItem** from **items.py**
Bug:

```
from example_bot.example_bot.items import ExampleDotcdComItem
```

modification:

```
from example_bot.example_bot.item import ExampleDotcdComItem
```